# Improve performance of dictionary with over 3000 entries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
import random

def gennum(count=1):
    num1=[]
    temp2={}
    for i in range(1,50):
        num1.append(i)
    for j in range(count):
        temp2[j]=random.sample(num1,7)
    return temp2

print(gennum(3000))
```

when i try to create more than 3000+ record.The speed is really really slow.The python shell become laggy and sometimes not responding.

1.The laggy is caused by the code or too many record created??

2.what is the maximum size of individual dictionary??

3.It would be grateful if anyone can recommend a book which covered all the topic in detail of python coz after i reading 2 python books explaining about the list ,dict etc. i cant find the solution to solve the above problem.

I am new in programming and my eng is not good .thanks for your patient!

Comment: Random number generation is slow. Recommending books, etc. is explicitly outside the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: The dictionary size is only limited by your memory, theoretically (ok, it's also limited by the maximum index an array can have on your platform). Constructing dictionaries of size 3000 should be really fast unless some part of that code is expensive. Random number generation is expensive. In any event, your code runs instantly on my machine...

Comment: Likewise; your code ran in about 1 second on my machine. One thing you could remove is the num1 list entirely; just use range itself to pick the random.sample from.

Comment: If you try to use list comprehension you will see it's a rocket compared to `for` loop, at least in my machine. But I don't think dictionaries are the reason behind your application being laggy, not at all.

Comment: thanks for reply. my machine is i5-3210m with16gb ram .i use the python idle and shell to run the code. I think i should divide the 3k + record into 3 session(1k each) and join it afterward. its seems much faster than create 3k record at once.
Abid Hasan suggesting use range + random.sample to implementing the code.How? Many books just only teaching the simple skill and method.How to learn different coding skill??

Comment: Consider whether you even *need* a dictionary; there is little difference semantically between a `dict` whose keys are a continuous sequence of integers starting with 0 and a `list`. `num1 = list(range(1,50)); temp2 = [random.sample(num1, 7) for _ in range(count)]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not actually the creation of the dictionary that's making the shell lag and not respond, it's because of the `print` statement, python IDLE(I presume) doesn't support printing that massive content. If you don't print but store it in a variable like this: `num = gennum(3000)`, to check, `print(len(gennum))` will output `3000`, it will finish instantly. If you seriously want to view it, try saving it into a text file and view it from there.

Side note: Running the script from a console (Terminal, cmd) will print properly without any problems because they can display up to 30000 chr but after that, the console will automatically delete the beginning to keep the total chr under the limit. But basically, it depends on your system.